# Как обойти проблему очерёдности создания таблиц с внешними ключами ссылающиеся друг на друга?

Tags: sql

У меня такая вот проблемка, надеюсь на понимание и помощь.
В запросе создаётся база данных, далее идёт создание таблиц(15 шт.). Имеются такие таблицы, что в 1ой таблице имеется внешний ключ на таблицу 2ую, но так же и во 2ой таблице имеется внешний ключ на 1ую таблицу. Как их расположить, чтоб не возникало ошибки, что мол при компиляции таблица 1 не может быть создана так как имеется колонка-внешний ключ на **не созданую таблицу 2**.
Имеется идея, создать 3ью таблицу, но как ***правильно*** её создать тогда, что в ней должно присутствовать?

Answer (score 5):

Создайте сначала таблицы без внешних ключей, а потом ключи отдельно.
Например:

```
CREATE TABLE `T1` (...)
CREATE TABLE `T2` (...)
...
CREATE TABLE `T15` (...)
ALTER TABLE `T1` ADD CONSTRAINT `C1` FOREIGN KEY (`F1`) REFERENCES `T2`(`F2`)
...
```

Comment: Хм...можно попробовать, спс.
А через 3 таблицы сможешь подсказать?

Comment: Честно говоря слабо представляю себе такую реализацию. Я б пересмотрел архитектуру, т.к. может быть опасно зацикливать таблицы таким образом. Может еще кто-нибудь чего предложит...

Comment: Поясни про зацикливание? т.е. вот про такую ситуацию, которую я описал? В концептуальной и реляционных моделях так выходит и так правильно. По другому не реализовать.

Answer (score 3):

Неправильная архитектура БД. 2 таблицы не должны взаимноссылаться друг на друга. Расскажите, для чего вам именно такие связи необходимы?
PS во внешних ключах.

Comment: БД Сервис-центра, таблица персонал и таблица клиент. После диагностики сотрудник(табл.персонал) должен оповестить клиента(табл.клиент) о том что мол выполнили диагностики стоимость такая, в ответ на это клиент должен сообщить сотруднику свой ответ согласен или нет на ремонт. Связть реализована в 2х направлениях по этому и имеются внешние ключи друг на друга. А я не вижу другого решения как связать эти 2 таблицы. По этому и использую внешние ключи друг для друга.

Comment: Таблица сотрудников. Таблица клиентов. Таблица принятия техники или чтото в этом роде, ссылающаяся на "Таблица сотрудников и Таблица клиентов". Если необходим диалог клиента - сотрудника то ещё одна таблица комментариев и пр, записи которой ссылаются на таблицы принятия техники (предпочитаемый вариант). Иначе - в таблице принятия техники пишем в одно поле неисправность со слов клиента, в другое результаты диагностики

Comment: Дилберт: О, нет! Предельный уровень абстракции сделал нас невесомыми!

Comment: Вот именно мне и хочется реализовать 3ью таблицу, на которую буду ссылатся и табл.клиент и табл.сотрудник, я и спросил как мне её правильно реализовать, что в ней должно быть и чего не должно.

Comment: Не знаю специфику вашего СЦ. Если дело касается только диагностики то абстрактно:
Таблица "Прием техники". Поля:
-Идентификатор
-Клиент(идентификатор)
-Принявший сотрудник(идентификатор)
-Диагностировавший сотрудник(идентификатор)
-Причина (неполадки со слов клиента)
-Результат диагностики
-Стоимость и т.д.
-флаг оплаты
-сумма оплаты
-Флаг дальнейшей работы с клиентом. (т.е. после диагностики последовал ремонт, замена комплектующих и пр. что должно отражаться уже в другой подсистеме вашего ПО)

Comment: Внешние ключи:
Поле Клиент ссылается на поле идентификатор Таблицы Клиенты
Поле Принявший сотрудник ссылается на поле идентификатор Таблицы Сотрудники
Поле Диагностировавший сотрудник ссылается на поле идентификатор Таблицы Сотрудникирибудет с вами сила.
Для всех ключей устанавливается политика:
Обновление - каскадно
Удаление - запрещено

И будет вам щастье. Да п

Answer (score 0):

Таблица сотрудников. Таблица клиентов. Таблица принятия техники или чтото в этом роде, ссылающаяся на "Таблица сотрудников и Таблица клиентов". Если необходим диалог клиента - сотрудника то ещё одна таблица комментариев и пр, записи которой ссылаются на таблицы принятия техники (предпочитаемый вариант). Иначе - в таблице принятия техники пишем в одно поле неисправность со слов клиента, в другое результаты диагностики.

Answer (score 0):

Транзакция... На псевдокоде как-то так:

```
Создать Запись в Таблице1 ( ID = Автоинкремент(), КлючТаблица2 = Null );
@key = ПоследнийАвтоинкремент(); 
Создать Запись в Таблице2 ( ID = Автоинкремент(), КлючТаблица1 = @key );
@key2 = ПоследнийАвтоинкремент();
Изменить Запись в Таблице1 где ID = @key задать КлючТаблица2 = @key2;
```